# Trying to create a generic function that balances values (unsure exactly how to word it)

Tags: javascript

Given an array like this:

```
var buckets = [
  {name: "bucket1", value: 10000},
    {name: "bucket2", value: -5000},
    {name: "bucket3", value: -2000},
]
```

I am trying to "zero out" the negative numbers. In every situation given, the total of all the values added together will never be negative. What I mean by "zero out" is take any positive numbers, and reduce them by the negative numbers, in the order in which they appear.

So if the first number and third number is negative, and the second number is positive, it will reduce the the second by the first, and then by the third.

The end values of my example afterwards would be 3000, 0, 0 - respectively.

The numbers can appear in any combination and order, as long as the sum of all of them are positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the best solution but something like this should work.

Pseudocode:

```
// for every item in the bucket
for(var i = 0; i < buckets.length; i++){

  // if the value of this bucket is negative
  if(buckets[i].value < 0) {

    // look through every bucket again
    for(var j = 0; j < buckets.length; j++) {

      // and if we find one that is positive
      if(buckets[j].value > 0) {

        // add all the positive to this negative
        buckets[i].value += buckets[j].value;

        // if it's still negative we are gonna start again
        if(buckets[i].value < 0) {

          i--;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Its not exactly what I wanted, but it gave me a good start to what I needed, gonna mark as accepted for your rep ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can perform `reduce` on the Array and separate the buckets by positive/negative values. then iterate over the negatives reducing each by a positive until it hits zero and moving onto the next as much as needed.

```js
var buckets=[{name:"bucket1",value:1e4},{name:"bucket2",value:-5e3},{name:"bucket3",value:-2e3}],
 result = buckets.reduce( ( a, v, i, {
  length
 } ) => {
  let isNeg = Math.sign( v.value ) == -1;
  isNeg ? a.n.push( v ) : a.p.push( v );
  if ( i < length - 1 ) {
   return a;
  } else {
   return [ ...a.n.map( n => {
    while ( n.value < 0 ) {
     let pos = a.p.find( ( {
       value
      } ) => value > 0 ),
      tval = n.value + pos.value,
      nval, posval;
     if ( tval >= 0 ) {
      nval = 0;
      posval = tval;
     } else {
      nval = tval;
      posval = pos.value + n.value;
     }
     pos.value = posval;
     n.value = nval;
    }
    return n;
   } ), ...a.p ]
  }
 }, {
  p: [],
  n: []
 } );
console.log( result );
```